# External IP pending ingress controller

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Iam facing wierd problem i was following a tutorial with stephen grider in microservices
i built skafold file and ingress service and 2 services one called auth and the other called client and this is output after running `skafold dev`

```
Listing files to watch...
 - moatazemadnaeem/auth
 - moatazemadnaeem/client
Generating tags...
 - moatazemadnaeem/auth -> moatazemadnaeem/auth:latest
 - moatazemadnaeem/client -> moatazemadnaeem/client:latest
Some taggers failed. Rerun with -vdebug for errors.
Checking cache...
 - moatazemadnaeem/auth: Found Locally
 - moatazemadnaeem/client: Found Locally
Tags used in deployment:
 - moatazemadnaeem/auth -> moatazemadnaeem/auth:02cc5bb4a3dd94ee5f02dcbeb23a8e7ba7308f12c55e701b6d5a50fd950df4da
 - moatazemadnaeem/client -> moatazemadnaeem/client:f6f4b9ce5f6c3f1655e6a902b6a5d7fa27e203ec75b6c8772a8ebe4b9c105dbd
Starting deploy...
 - deployment.apps/auth-depl created
 - service/auth-srv created
 - deployment.apps/mongo-depl created
 - service/auth-mongo-srv created
 - deployment.apps/client-depl created
 - service/client-srv created
 - ingress.networking.k8s.io/ingress-srv created
Waiting for deployments to stabilize...
 - deployment/client-depl is ready. [2/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/auth-depl is ready. [1/3 deployment(s) still pending]
 - deployment/mongo-depl is ready.
Deployments stabilized in 3.103 seconds
Press Ctrl+C to exit
Watching for changes...
[client] 
[auth] 
[auth] > auth@1.0.0 start
[auth] > nodemon ./src/index.ts
[auth] 
[auth] [nodemon] 2.0.15
[auth] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[client] > client@1.0.0 dev
[auth] [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[client] > next
[auth] [nodemon] watching extensions: ts,json
[client] 
[auth] [nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts`
[client] ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
[auth] connected to db
[auth] listening in port 3000
[client] event - compiled client and server successfully in 2.8s (185 modules)
[client] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[client] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[client] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[client] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[client]
```

and this is my ingress service

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-srv
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

and here is my skafold file

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2alpha3
kind: Config
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - ./infra/k8s/*
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: moatazemadnaeem/auth
      context: auth
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "src/**/*.ts"
            dest: .
    - image: moatazemadnaeem/client
      context: client
      docker:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "**/*.js"
            dest: .
```

every thing was working fine until i decided to resize my docker disk every image deleted all containers etc...
so i started from the beginning first i need to apply the ingress controller after applying it

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.1/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

everything seems to work api pod is working and connected to Database
but after reaching out ticketing.dev the website is not responding
so i troubleshoot and figure out that ingress controller does not have external ip its in the state pending (**forever**)

```
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.103.240.204   <pending>     80:31413/TCP,443:30200/TCP   34s
```

and here is logs of ingress-controller i used this command `kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd`

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       v1.1.1
  Build:         a17181e43ec85534a6fea968d95d019c5a4bc8cf
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.19.9

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

W0213 04:09:10.888703       7 client_config.go:615] Neither --kubeconfig nor --master was specified.  Using the inClusterConfig.  This might not work.
I0213 04:09:10.888860       7 main.go:223] "Creating API client" host="https://10.96.0.1:443"
I0213 04:09:10.900669       7 main.go:267] "Running in Kubernetes cluster" major="1" minor="22" git="v1.22.4" state="clean" commit="b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1" platform="linux/arm64"
I0213 04:09:10.982532       7 main.go:104] "SSL fake certificate created" file="/etc/ingress-controller/ssl/default-fake-certificate.pem"
I0213 04:09:10.994820       7 ssl.go:531] "loading tls certificate" path="/usr/local/certificates/cert" key="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0213 04:09:11.003072       7 nginx.go:255] "Starting NGINX Ingress controller"
I0213 04:09:11.009752       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"ConfigMap", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller", UID:"10ad2461-56de-4c14-9614-3d341476a118", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"3699", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'CREATE' ConfigMap ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx-controller
I0213 04:09:12.206706       7 nginx.go:297] "Starting NGINX process"
I0213 04:09:12.206782       7 leaderelection.go:248] attempting to acquire leader lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader...
I0213 04:09:12.207597       7 nginx.go:317] "Starting validation webhook" address=":8443" certPath="/usr/local/certificates/cert" keyPath="/usr/local/certificates/key"
I0213 04:09:12.207902       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:09:12.234784       7 leaderelection.go:258] successfully acquired lease ingress-nginx/ingress-controller-leader
I0213 04:09:12.236967       7 status.go:84] "New leader elected" identity="ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd"
I0213 04:09:12.309234       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:09:12.309306       7 controller.go:183] "Initial sync, sleeping for 1 second"
I0213 04:09:12.309339       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:17:36.404962       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 04:17:36.406104       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"bf9349f3-9e16-44b4-876f-e1ee0de9ea51", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"4833", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 04:17:39.645534       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:17:39.739356       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:17:39.739891       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 04:19:14.912300       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 04:19:14.914196       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:19:15.132889       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:19:15.134516       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
2022/02/13 04:19:17 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:63670: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0213 04:19:18.246782       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:19:18.330122       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:19:18.330756       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:19:51.033718       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 04:19:51.035689       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"fe4c4a5c-8186-475e-b862-3574c995394e", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"5233", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 04:19:54.271841       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:19:54.382188       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:19:54.382524       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 04:36:53.789772       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 04:36:53.792021       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:36:54.084136       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:36:54.089358       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:36:57.122506       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:36:57.194378       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:36:57.194546       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
2022/02/13 04:37:12 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:62628: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0213 04:37:47.079701       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 04:37:47.081605       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"a538b7de-9b58-4ced-83a2-2f7f91972e3d", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"6949", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 04:37:50.324726       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:37:50.466695       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:37:50.467301       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 04:41:45.984007       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 04:41:45.986154       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:41:46.239624       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:41:46.242229       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:41:49.312445       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:41:49.382286       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:41:49.382557       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:42:34.030470       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 04:42:34.032340       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"baeaac48-a580-4334-9c6d-e5ec9b9322fd", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"7459", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 04:42:37.264159       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:42:37.350956       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:42:37.351720       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 04:51:07.915558       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 04:51:07.917577       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:51:08.145057       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:51:08.147466       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 04:51:11.249421       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 04:51:11.326464       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 04:51:11.326711       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 05:02:51.329191       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/demo" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 05:02:51.329962       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"demo", UID:"b2009c54-0c51-46ac-bc00-52946563d25f", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"9220", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 05:02:51.335381       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 05:02:51.444871       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 05:02:51.445228       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 05:11:52.100612       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 05:11:52.101829       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"67c8b6ed-6449-4710-bb0c-05132287ce6a", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"10007", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 05:11:55.348373       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 05:11:55.485075       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 05:11:55.486547       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 05:16:56.655485       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 05:16:56.655708       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 05:16:56.868807       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 05:16:56.869459       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 05:16:59.992987       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 05:17:00.060763       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 05:17:00.060950       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
2022/02/13 16:10:58 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:65258: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2022/02/13 16:11:02 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:65322: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2022/02/13 16:11:05 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:65360: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0213 16:12:09.427485       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 16:12:09.428413       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"1d7284a4-9337-4394-97bc-9e50311bfd14", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"11403", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 16:12:12.658798       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 16:12:12.768695       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 16:12:12.769331       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 16:34:00.171544       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 16:34:00.177362       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 16:34:00.404447       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 16:34:00.405281       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 16:34:03.508701       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 16:34:03.580855       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 16:34:03.581050       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
2022/02/13 16:34:18 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:56440: remote error: tls: bad certificate
2022/02/13 17:19:25 http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.65.3:62284: remote error: tls: bad certificate
I0213 17:19:51.751884       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 17:19:51.753174       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"fb63a4c5-437f-4737-a4c2-4cfc581fe560", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"14499", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 17:19:54.977214       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 17:19:55.179125       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 17:19:55.181141       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 17:44:53.550406       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"fb63a4c5-437f-4737-a4c2-4cfc581fe560", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"16638", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
W0213 18:06:01.779080       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 18:06:01.780145       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 18:06:02.062236       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 18:06:02.071438       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 18:06:04.757208       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 18:06:04.758134       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"982dc419-95cb-45cd-938d-6150a5732baa", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"18548", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
W0213 18:06:05.110417       7 controller.go:1083] Service "default/auth-srv" does not have any active Endpoint.
W0213 18:06:05.110441       7 controller.go:1083] Service "default/client-srv" does not have any active Endpoint.
I0213 18:06:05.110548       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 18:06:05.202121       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 18:06:05.202707       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
W0213 18:11:48.540680       7 controller.go:988] Error obtaining Endpoints for Service "default/auth-srv": no object matching key "default/auth-srv" in local store
I0213 18:11:48.543520       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 18:11:48.755536       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 18:11:48.758696       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 18:11:51.877652       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 18:11:51.987030       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 18:11:51.987707       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
I0213 18:11:52.600029       7 store.go:424] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ingress-srv" ingressclass="nginx"
I0213 18:11:52.603754       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"default", Name:"ingress-srv", UID:"cfcc5c54-e596-4fd6-80d0-a8c1689261ff", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"19149", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'Sync' Scheduled for sync
I0213 18:11:55.205772       7 controller.go:155] "Configuration changes detected, backend reload required"
I0213 18:11:55.273789       7 controller.go:172] "Backend successfully reloaded"
I0213 18:11:55.274700       7 event.go:282] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"ingress-nginx", Name:"ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd", UID:"10331660-de0e-4f65-8519-38c834383472", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"4068", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'RELOAD' NGINX reload triggered due to a change in configuration
moataznaeem@moatazs-air ticketing %
```

and after digging and digging there is no way to solve this issue so please any help

Comment: Can you post the controller logs and also describe the ingress load balancer to see the current situation? Have you looked at them?

Comment: Yeah but it does not make any sense to me i used `kubectl logs -n ingress-nginx ingress-nginx-controller-54d8b558d4-bwjjd` but the result was meaningless

Comment: Hmm, did you describe the ingress? How about its output?

Comment: i do not the command to get the namespace of resource `kubectl get ing -n <namespace-of-ingress-resource>` it tell me no resource found `kubectl get ing -n ingress-nginx                  
No resources found in ingress-nginx namespace.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after many many hours of digging i got stuck so i decided to re-install docker
and started fresh for somehow External ip (localhost) got assigned to LoadBalancer so i test it and everything is working now.